# Can't install Ettercap with Graphical mode using Homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew, sniffing

I can't install Ettercap to my OSX 10.7.8 using homebrew. Homebrew allowed me to install Ettercap but I can't rub it with graphical mode somehow.

```
➜  ~  ettercap -G

ettercap 0.7.6 copyright 2001-2013 Ettercap Development Team

GTK support is not compiled in ettercap
```

I would appreciate it if you can guide me through the steps to successfully install ettercap with graphical mode at my OSX mountain lion.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To install Ettercap with the graphical mode with Homebrew, you can use the option `--with-gtk+`

```
$ brew install ettercap --with-gtk+
```

For your own information, you can get details about options on any Homebrew formula with `brew info [formula]`

Issuing `brew info ettercap` in the Terminal will show something like

```
ettercap: stable 0.8.0, HEAD
http://ettercap.github.io/ettercap/
/usr/local/Cellar/ettercap/0.8.0 (69 files, 2,1M) *
  Built from source with: --with-gtk+, --with-ipv6
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/commits/master/Library/Formula/ettercap.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: cmake ✔, ghostscript ✘
Required: pcre ✔, libnet ✔, curl ✔
Optional: ghostscript ✘, gtk+ ✔, luajit ✘
==> Options
--with-ghostscript
    Build with ghostscript support
--with-gtk+
    Build with gtk+ support
--with-ipv6
    Install with IPv6 support
--with-luajit
    Build with luajit support
--without-curses
    Install without curses interface
--without-plugins
    Install without plugins support
--HEAD
    install HEAD version
```

**Note**: in order to use this graphical mode, you also need to install [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/)

Comment: For anyone who already installed. `brew reinstall ettercap --with-gtk+`

Comment: This solution no longer works `Error: invalid option: --with-gtk+`

Comment: The new version has the GTK3 built-in. It's just needed to install the icons manually: `brew install adwaita-icon-theme`

Answer (score 3):

Newer version of ettercap now work when installed from homebrew, however you must ensure you have the `adwaita-icon-theme` package installed aswell

```
brew install ettercap
brew install adwaita-icon-theme
```

https://github.com/Ettercap/ettercap/wiki/macosx